# How to send ADA (Cardano) signed transaction to testnet?

Tags: transactions, cardano

I have made an ADA signed transaction using [this documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cardano-wallet) successfully. What I need now is to submit it on testnet networks like [cardanoscan](https://testnet.cardanoscan.io/transactions). After searching the net, unfortunately I did not find any explorer api to send the transaction. Could anyone help please?

Comment: did you signed it on the mainnet?

Comment: No, I signed it on the testnet, it seems there are not any public nodes for testnet. I tried to change the local pc to a node. After it, I could send the transaction normally.